# bash HMACSHA1 code to Ruby

Tags: ruby, bash, encoding

I'm trying to re-write the following bash code in Ruby:

```
export PRIVATE_KEY="my-private-key"

echo -n $(iconv -c -f UTF-8 -t US-ASCII <<EOF
{
  "tenantId": "$TENANT",
  "username": "$USERNAME",
  "password": "$PASSWORD",
  "rememberMe" : 1,
  "timestamp": "${TIMESTAMP}"
}
EOF
) >${BODY}

export SIGN_HASH=$(cat ${BODY} | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac ${PRIVATE_KEY} -binary | openssl enc -base64)
```

So far this is what I came with:

```
TIMESTAMP = Time.now.to_f
body = { tenantId: "tenant", username: "nnuser", password: "password", rememberMe: "1", timestamp: TIMESTAMP }
hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha1'), PRIVATE_KEY.encode("ASCII"), body.to_s.encode("ASCII"))
sign_hash = Base64.encode64(hmac)
```

But the result strings are different, and the one from Ruby is not working. Also, the bash code returns a 28 characters `SIGN_HASH` while in the Ruby code `sign_hash` is 64 characters long.

Comment: Instead of converting the hash to a string, I'd strongly recommend using JSON to serialize the information. The string version will send the symbols/keys as the stringified version of the symbol, which other languages won't understand, and you'll have to decode or munge. JSON will convert them to their string form prior to serializing, which will then make it very easy to digest/reuse the data in any language supporting JSON. Even if you're only sending to another Ruby processes, the use of JSON will make it easier for you when you decode the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 2 things wrong with your code:

The initial string is different: calling `to_s` on your hash won't produce output formatted like your bash script (try it in the console).

You're using `hexdigest` which outputs the hash as 40 hexadecimal characters rather then the 20 byte binary output that you want (which is produced by the `digest` method)